# Resharper rename feature similar to Visual Studio rename - is it possible?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, usability

When you're using Visual Studio refactoring features you may change the name of variable / class name, etc., press ctrl + . and you're able to apply rename to this change. When you're using Resharper you have to say up front that you want to rename it (you have to press ctrl + r + r or f2). Is it possible in Resharper to change the name and then say you wanted full rename?

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: What do you mean by "full rename" ?

Comment: @Nacereddine - He probably means the feature that changes the name wherever the symbol is referenced (and where relevant, the filename).

Comment: @odes I just wanted to make sure because resharper already has this !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. [Starting from version 6.0](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/index.html#Inplace), you can change the name of a symbol declaration first, and press Alt+Enter to apply the in-place rename refactoring. Similar in-place rename functionality is available for "Change signature" and "Move static members" refactorings.
Note that this only works when you're at symbol declarations. If you want to rename a symbol from its usage, you still have to use the regular Rename refactoring available via F2.